# Do not display the initial value in the customize component created with react and matrial-ui

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to create a customize component.
we use material-ui in react.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';    
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class MyTextField extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.value) {          
      this.setState({data: nextProps.value})
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({data: event.target.value});
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {

    return (<Grid container={true} spacing={1}>
      <TextField label={this.props.title} required= 
          {this.props.required} value={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
     </Grid>)
  }
```

with this code use the MyTextFiled :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';    
import MyTextField from '../../components/textField';

export default class add extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'this is init value'
    }
  }

  handleTitleChange(event) {
    if (event) {
      let val = event.target.value
      this.setState({title: val});
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <MyTextField value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)}/>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

But the value "this is init value" is not displayed in MyTextField.
If I enter a new value, it will be displayed...
This problem is not when I use "input" and only occurs when using "TextField" material.

Comment: Use `defaultValue` prop on the `TextField`.

Comment: thanks but I do not understand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved

```
if (props && props.value){
  this.state = {
    data: props.value
  }
}
```

add above code to constructor :)